# Ignore common records from both array and set property of unmatch record of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This are my 2 arrays :

```
$scope.Array1 =
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Abc",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Pqr",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Lmn",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Ggg",
      "selected": false
    }
  ],
}


$scope.obj.Array2 = ["Abc"];
```

Now when I have 2 modes that is add mode and edit mode so when there will be add mode I will have  $scope.obj.Array2 as undefined so at that time I would like to set selected property to true for all records of Array1.

But now when I will have edit mode I would like to ignore matching records from Array1 and so I would like to set only `Pqr,Lmn and GGG selected property to true.`

So basically I am doing check and uncheck all from Array1 and while edit mode I would like to ignore common records  for check/uncheck.

**Code:**

```
 angular.forEach($scope.Array1, function (item, index) {
                        item.selected = $scope.checkAllFlag;  //This will be either true of false
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the data you have provided, you can try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Array1, function (item, index) {
                        if(!$scope.obj.Array2 || !$scope.obj.Array2[item.name])
                            item.selected = $scope.checkAllFlag;  
                });
```

Comment: But during add mode my $scope.obj.Array2 would be undefined

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Sorry but in edit mode i am able to check/uncheck matchhing records also.In edit mode this condition gets true !$scope.obj.Array2 that is why i am still able to check/uncheck matching records